# Is there a simple way to unset an item in an array added using layout xml?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, template

Magento 2 comes with the following layout update in the Magento_Weee module:

```
<referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="adjustments" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tax" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="adjustment_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Weee\Pricing\Render\TaxAdjustment</item>
                        <item name="adjustment_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax::pricing/adjustment.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="weee" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="adjustment_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Weee\Pricing\Render\Adjustment</item>
                        <item name="adjustment_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Weee::pricing/adjustment.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

However, what if I want to remove this renderer? For as far as I know there is no such thing as:

```
<item name="weee" xsi:type="array" remove="true">
```

So if I want to remove the template I either have to do something like:

- Replacing the template with a blank file, or:
- Write a plugin for the class that's responsible for the rendering to disable the rendering at some points, or:
- Remove the blocks by names (but the names are dynamic (`magento\weee\pricing\render\adjustment_0`, etc.))

So how can I achieve this? Can it even be done in a simple matter? I don't like the idea to add all kind of PHP code to remove a small element from my frontend.